# Node.js JSON nested array object access

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, express

I am building an application which GETS JSON response from an API call in SONARQUBE.

Using node js how do I access the value of **duplicated_lines** from the below JSON object.

I tried the below but always get undefined. Is there any library that supports exploring these objects?

**Code**

```
var subrequest = unirest("GET",queryUrl);

subrequest.end(function (resXX) {
  if (resXX.error);
    for (var key in resXX) { 
      if (resXX.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log("Checking the id " + resXX[key].msr.duplicated_lines);
      }
    }
});
```

**JSON**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1933853,
    "uuid": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "key": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "name": "XXXXXXX",
    "scope": "PRJ",
    "qualifier": "TRK",
    "date": "2018-02-16T08:07:55-0500",
    "creationDate": "2017-09-20T09:50:05-0400",
    "lname": "XXXXXXXX",
    "version": "15",
    "msr": [
      {
        "key": "duplicated_lines",
        "val": 926192,
        "frmt_val": "926,192"
      },
      {
        "key": "bugs",
        "val": 7467,
        "frmt_val": "7,467"
      },
      {
        "key": "ncloc",
        "val": 1369829,
        "frmt_val": "1,369,829"
      },
      {
        "key": "code_smells",
        "val": 22677,
        "frmt_val": "22,677"
      },
      {
        "key": "vulnerabilities",
        "val": 95,
        "frmt_val": "95"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know anything about the API you are accessing, and your code is hard to interpret in the absence of any other information. However msr is an array, so you need to access the objects in it with an index:

```
resXX[key].msr.forEach(m => {
    if (m.key === 'duplicated_lines') {
        console.log('Checking the id ' + m.val);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> I tried the below but always get undefined

Because you are trying to use object `value` as `key` while accessing.

**Try this single line of code :**

```
var duplicateData = jsonObj[0].msr.filter(item => item.key == 'duplicated_lines');
```

**Working Demo**

```js
var jsonObj = [
  {
    "id": 1933853,
    "uuid": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "key": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "name": "XXXXXXX",
    "scope": "PRJ",
    "qualifier": "TRK",
    "date": "2018-02-16T08:07:55-0500",
    "creationDate": "2017-09-20T09:50:05-0400",
    "lname": "XXXXXXXX",
    "version": "15",
    "msr": [
      {
        "key": "duplicated_lines",
        "val": 926192,
        "frmt_val": "926,192"
      },
      {
        "key": "bugs",
        "val": 7467,
        "frmt_val": "7,467"
      },
      {
        "key": "ncloc",
        "val": 1369829,
        "frmt_val": "1,369,829"
      },
      {
        "key": "code_smells",
        "val": 22677,
        "frmt_val": "22,677"
      },
      {
        "key": "vulnerabilities",
        "val": 95,
        "frmt_val": "95"
      }
    ]
  }
];

var duplicateData = jsonObj[0].msr.filter(item => item.key == 'duplicated_lines');

console.log(duplicateData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a single line solution that iterates on the response JSON Array

```
resXX.forEach(item => item.msr.forEach(v => v['key']==='duplicated_lines' && console.log(`Checking the id ${v['val']}`)))
```